# Why does Protobuf inject bytes in my messages?

Tags: python, c++, protocol-buffers

I have two programs that exchange information via protocol buffers serialization. One of my data fields is in protobuf's `bytes` format, and it somehow has a few extra bytes after decoding.

That said, `0xDEADBEEF0123456789` becomes `0xFFFFFFDEFFFFFFADFFFFFFBEFFFFFFEF01234567FFFFFF89`.

My `messages.proto` file:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

message RawPacket {
    uint32 version = 1;
    oneof proto_trait {
        string protocol = 2;
        uint32 tcpport = 4;
        uint32 udpport = 5;
    };
    bytes data = 3;
}
```

The encoder code in python:

```py
import sys
import protocol.messages_pb2 as pb

...

payload = bytes.fromhex('deadbeef0123456789')

msg = pb.RawPacket()
msg.version = 1
msg.protocol = "Frame"
msg.data = payload

with open(sys.argv[1], 'wb') as f:
    f.write(msg.SerializeToString())
```

The decoder code in C++:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "protocol/messages.pb.h"

std::fstream inputfile{"some filename", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary};

RawPacket input;
if (!input.ParseFromIstream(&inputfile)) {
    std::cerr << "Could not parse raw packet." << std::endl;
    return 2;
}

// input.data() is a const std::string&, and I think that's suspicious.
for (char c : input.data()) {
    printf("%.2X", c);
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: `9` is not a valid hex digit. I'm not sure what Python is doing in that case, but I'd check the length of `bytes` before passing it to the proto

Comment: 9 is not a valid hex digit? Of course it is.

Comment: `9` is a valid hex digit, it 0-9 and a-f are. The length is also correct, it's even.

Comment: `for (char c : input.data()) ` can not possibly compile. Please provide MCVE.

Comment: It compiles since C++11, because input.data() is a string. (See: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-40-foreach-in-c-and-java/ )

Also sorry, but what is an MCVE?

Comment: `%.2X` expects an integer, as `char` is signed, characters over `7f` cast to a negative integer